# How do I take a user's input to update a JSON file in my project programmatically?

Tags: json, xcode, swift

In my iOS project, I have a JSON file used to set parameters. I'd like to take a user's input and use it as a parameter. For instance, a user fills in his ZIP code, the JSON file is updated with the ZIP code and the data for that ZIP code is retrieved.

How do I take a user's input to update a JSON file in my project programmatically?

Edit:

Essentially, this says to use the blockerList.json file in my main bundle:

```
class ActionRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

func beginRequestWithExtensionContext(context: NSExtensionContext) {
    let attachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("blockerList", withExtension: "json"))!

    let item = NSExtensionItem()
    item.attachments = [attachment]

    context.completeRequestReturningItems([item], completionHandler: nil);
}

}
```

What if I could make it use JSON data from somewhere else and have the request use that instead? Is that possible, and how would I implement that? Sorry, this is new to me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried reading in the file, changing the value to the input, and writing the file again?

Comment: I have not - I have no idea how to read/ write the JSON data, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due app security and sandboxing, files in app bundle cannot be overwritten. However, you can update a JSON stored outside of your app bundle, e.g. `Documents` directory.

This is how you will save data:

```
-(void)saveJSONWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *documentsDiretory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSString *path = [documentsDiretory stringByAppendingFormat:@“/myData.json"];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

This is how you will retrieve it:

```
NSString *fileName = @"myData.json”;
NSURL *documentsFolderURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsFolderURL.path stringByAppendingString:fileName];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *jsonError;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

So, technically, fetch your saved JSON in NDMutableDictionary, append data and save back. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I didn't clarify the language but I can figure out the Swift implementation for this.